# как объединить Arraylist и Set в одну переменную

Tags: java

Вопрос в том, что надо `ArrayList listA`, объединить с `Set listB`.

Я пробовал сделать как с обычными переменными:

```
listB  = listA;
```

Но оно так не работает, пишет что нельзя соединить Set c ArrayList.

А как по-другому?

Comment: что значит объединить?

Answer (score 2):

В родительском интерфейсе `Collection` существует метод [`Collection::addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-), позволяющий добавить все элементы одной коллекции в другую.

Следует заметить, что результаты добавления списка `List` в множество `Set` и множества в список будут разные в зависимости от типа коллекции-приёмника, которая должна быть изменяемой (mutable).

```
List<ObjA> listA;
Set<ObjA> setA;
listA.addAll(setA); // обычное добавление элементов

List<ObjB> listB;
Set<ObjB> setB;
setB.addAll(listB); // дубликаты не будут добавлены в setB
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо такой простой ответ оказался, как я сам не додумался

Comment: @Kronos, [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Сложно предположить что вы имели ввиду под "объединить". Может вам поможет вот это:

```
listB = new HashSet<>(listA);
```

Comment: Этот код создаст новый сет из списка `listA`, содержимое `setB` будет утеряно.  Но может в этом и состоит сермяжная правда объединения.